# problem with VB QUery

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

Anything wrong with the following query? subquery works fine but not the complete query :(

```
strNewSql1 = "SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber & '_' & tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl FROM tblEventLog" & _
            "WHERE (tblEventLog.PartNumber & '_' & tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl) NOT IN " & _
            "(SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber & '_' & tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl " & _
            "FROM tblEventLog " & _
            "WHERE tblEventLog.EventTypeSelected = 'pn REMOVED From Wrapper')" & _
            "AND tblEventLog.TrackingNumber = """ & tempTrackingNumber & """"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space between tblEventLog and WHERE.

```
"SELECT tblEventLog.PartNumber & '_' & tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl FROM tblEventLog" & _
        "<ADD SPACE>WHERE (tblEventLog.PartNumber & '_' & tblEventLog.PartNumberChgLvl) NOT IN " & _
```

Comment: And another between the end of the subquery and the final AND condition (end of the second-to-last line).

Comment: A good practice to get into when building queries this way is to start each new concatenated line with a space: `" WHERE..."`, Makes the spaces easier to see & harder to forget, and if you get extras it doesn't hurt anything.